# Chrome(driver) basic authentication .... again

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, authentication, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Query mainly due to trying to do this using Selenium but I see exactly the same behaviour if I repeat manually so I guess it's a general Chrome question.

So what I'm trying to do is use Chrome with some Selenium tests. Tests happen on a remote machine running 64 bit Ubuntu Linux (running Selenium Server) and are driven from my machine running 64 bit W7 Pro. Scripting is done in Python. Chrome is up to date, Selenium Server is up to date, as is Chromedriver.

The site I'm working on (still in development) uses a lot of AJAX/jQuery calls. It uses basic authentication to log you in.

Using Chrome, if I pass in the login credentials in the URL (as you have to with Selenium it seems) it gets me onto the site OK. Page navigation works OK. But AJAX requests fail as the basic authentication credentials are not added to the header for the request. If I log in via standard URL (manually enter ID + PW) the AJAX requests work OK. I see the same behaviour on Linux and Windows if I try it manually. Using FireFox, it all works OK - the AJAX requests have the authentication header as they're supposed to, regardless how you authenticate. Credentials are carried through correctly throughout. I've checked all the requests using Fiddler and can see the missing header for the Chrome AJAX request when passing in the credentials via the URL.

I did try and use the popup login box instead, but that appears to be a non-starter. Selenium hangs on the initial GET, and until you clear the popup, control is not passed back to the script. So I have no way of sending keys to it. I also tried navigating by using window.location.href = "url" directly, instead of the selenium "get". No luck that way either. And finally, if I reduce the page load timeout, wait for it to fail, and then try and pick up the popup, that doesn't work either. When it times out, the popup is removed.

At this point. I've just about given up. I can't use user profiles as it's a daily changing password (work thing) so theres no point in storing it.

I'm not the developer. I don't know JavaScript terribly well. I've spoken to the lead dev and their response is that this is a Chrome bug and nothing they can fix.

Does anyone concur? Or have a way round this. I'm snookered at the moment because of it ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing Basic authentication issues, try authenticateUsing() method.

The Alert Method, `authenticateUsing()` lets you skip the **Http Basic Authentication** box.

> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
>   Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
>   alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("**USERNAME**", "**PASSWORD**"));

PS: Change the syntax for Python bindings

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Couple of problems though. 1 - I don't see any mention of that method in the Python bindings documentation. But the bigger problem is 2 - The page GET blocks until the popup is cleared - control is not passed back to the script. If it times out, the popup still clears. So I can't actually get to the popup to perform any actions on it in the first place (when using Chrome).

Comment: I'm going to have to try that.   Hopefully this method works when using Java and is able to work on a  .htaccess  password prompt.